# Black Ops II theater successfully render movie clips but doesn't upload it to YouTube

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I finished installing Black Ops II yesterday. First I connected my YouTube channel and tried to render some of my edited movies. After rendering, [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzaN3.jpg) was displayed, but non of the videos seems to be uploaded to YouTube channel. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyKzU.jpg) confirm that i have successfully connected YouTube, Facebook and Steam accounts to Call Of Duty profile. I tried to google the issue, and I found some old questions by the time OPS II is released. It used to be a bug long time ago which was fixed lately.
Are there any solution? Where can I report this issue directly for those who are responsible?